# How to build openjdk image for windows?

Tags: java, makefile, build, windows-subsystem-for-linux, configure

With WSL, i managed to clone the mercurial repository of `jdk8u` , run `get_source` , `configure` ,
`make` all succesfully.
The fact is that when i run `make` it builds the jdk image for linux, but i want to build the jdk image for windows.
According to https://openjdk.java.net/groups/build/doc/building.html , by default, it should build the jdk for windows, so this is already strange. However, that guide says that if i want to build for Windows i must have a Windows jdk as boot jdk.

This is where i get stuck: how can a jdk made for windows, work in linux? **And how to install it, and get it work?**

Note 2 things: the boot jdk i am using right now comes from `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`. I also already tried to use the windows jdk in linux, by replacing `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\usr\lib\jvm\java-8-openjdk-amd64` with the Windows jdk 8, but didn't work because obviously, .exe cannot run in linux.

**So what does this guide mean**  [here ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDxDN.png)

Comment: I have the same problem and just like you, I don't understand how that would work. It even says "The default behavior is to build for Windows". But from my perspective, the default is to build for Linux. (Probably because I am using boot JDK for Linux)
Have you found a solution?
I guess I'll go the Cygwin way.

Comment: The OpenJDK guide is for newer versions of JDK. Indeed, mainline defaults to building for Windows in WSL.